# How is there money still left for Emilio Lopez?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-deeds

In *Mr Deeds* (2002), Longfellow Deeds donated the whole $40 Billion to the United Negro College Fund.

At the end of the movie, Babe Bennett announces that Emilio Lopez is the true heir to Preston Blake.

Emilio Lopez celebrates with news and  **thanks Deeds for his support and offers him a billion dollars**.

How is there money still left for Emilio Lopez?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, although he did give away the money...**it wasn't his to give**, so the whole transaction would have been invalid.

As Babe Bennett says when she produces Preston Blake's diary..

> Also, when Deeds gave away his fortune, he gave away something that wasn't his.

So, the money would have had to be returned by the charity...even though they'd already received the cheque.

[image]